# Issue with a PHP Online Order Form

Tags: php, html

I've created a contact form for a website with multiple fields. The clear button works perfectly, but when I click the Submit button, I inadvertently download the .php file associated with the webpage, instead of sending an email with the order form to the specified address. I'm really new to php here, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$field_quantity = $_POST['cf_quantity'];
$field_which = $_POST['cf_which'];
$field_size = $_POST['cf_size'];
$field_school = $_POST['cf_school'];
$field_college = $_POST['cf_college'];
$field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];

$mail_to = 'xxx@gmail.com';
$subject = 'TShirt Order - xxx.Org '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail Address: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Quantity of Shirts: '.$field_quantity."\n";
$body_message .= 'Shirt Style(s): '.field_which."\n";
$body_message .= 'Size(s): '.field_size."\n";
$body_message .= 'School: '.field_school."\n";
$body_message .= 'College: '.field_college."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Thank you for placing an order with xxx.Org. We will contact you shortly.');
        window.location = 'contact_page.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to xxx@gmail.com');
    window.location = 'contact_page.html';
    </script>
<?php 
}
?>
```

the html code is:

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post">
Full Name:
<input type="text" name="cf_name">
<br />
<br />
Email Address:
<input type="text" name="cf_email">
<br />
<br />
Quantity of TShirts:
<input type="numeric" name="cf_quantity">
<br />
<br />
Which Style(s)?
<input type="text" name="cf_which">
<br />
<br />
Size(s):
<input type="text" name="cf_size">
<br />
<br />
Name of School:
<input type="text" name="cf_school">
<br />
<br />
Name of College:
<input type="text" name="cf_college">
<br />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>
```

Comment: Won't help with the issue you're having at all, but `<input type="numeric"` is an error - I think you're after `<input type="number"`.

Comment: if you were to create a hello.php page, eliminating any of the interaction between the form and the contact.php page, would hello.php mis-behave the same way?

Comment: This is very likely to be a configuration issue, did you install php yourself?

Comment: Are you running this on a web server that has PHP installed? Usually if you make a request for a page/file on a server running PHP, it will process the PHP. Otherwise, it will just try to download it like any other file.

Comment: Also, there's some massive security holes in that form mailing script, it'd be very easy for a spammer to hijack it and use your server to send out thousands of spam messages. Might pay to ensure that is fixed before going live.

Comment: I never installed php - I'm just working off of Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Are you completely sure the server accepts php? Seams to me the server doesn't understand it should use the php interpeter and instead of activating the php commands it just lets you download the file.

If you're not sure try and make a file with a simple  in it, call that and see if it works.

best regards,

Mark

Comment: Preferably a file with this code: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`. That will tell you everything you need to know about your PHP install.

Comment: right now, I'm just working on the file locally (on my laptop). I want to make absolutely certain that it works before uploading it. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Install a development web server on your laptop. XAMPP seems to be a popular one and easy to use. http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html